# Filestream Dispose information

Tags: c#, file

I know that `dispose` method is used for garbage collecting funtionality.
But in this example, I don't know precisely what `dispose` does in `Filestream`

```
FileStream fl = new FileStream("file1.txt",FileMode.Open);
fl.Dispose();
```

Comment: Then you know something wrong. Dispose is about disposing of resources *other than* memory. Garbage Collection is just about memory.

Comment: What you mean saying resources in Filestream

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `FileStream` opens a file. Disposing the `FileStream` closes that file. If you're going to do it explicitly, you ought to call `Close` rather than `Dispose`, although either is OK. You shouldn't do it explicitly though. You should create the object with a `using` statement and then it will be implicitly disposed:

```cs
using (var fs = new FileStream("file1.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    // Use fs here.
}
```